# Вопрос по JQuery append

Tags: jquery

вставляю код
$("#menu_editor").append('<div id="btn_menu3" class="btn_menu">Пункт меню</div>');
появляется надпись "Пункт меню" а стиль описанный в классе btn_menu к нему не применяется =(
класс btn_menu описан на странице в разделе <style>

почему при вставке нового элемента не применяется стиль?

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию, все должно работать. Разметку, стили и код в студию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

неправильно описан стиль как его просмотреть, где пример jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/qzgpX/

Не работать не может.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
.btn_menu{
border:4px red solid;
width:130px;
heigth:50px;
border-radius:15px;
background:blue;
color:red;
float:left;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
margin:2px;
font-weight:bold;
cursor:pointer;
}
вот описание класса стиля, сам не пойму в чем проблема? просто недавно JQuery использую, думаю может тонкость какая есть.

при нажатии F5 стиль применяется, но я делаю динамическое меню и как бы хотелось чтобы при вставке стиль применялся.

Comment: вообщем пока сделал так
$("#menu_editor").append('<div id="btn_menu3" class="btn_menu" style="border:4px red solid; width:130px; heigth:50px; border-radius:15px; background:blue; color:red; float:left; padding:5px; text-align:center; margin:2px; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;">Пункт меню</div>');

Comment: Вот jsfiddle все работает 

http://jsfiddle.net/qzgpX/

Comment: странно... =)

Comment: @FrancNet, если у всех все работает, но не у Вас - в первую очередь необходимо очистить кэш браузера.

Comment: DreamWeaver виновником был, там же тестовый сервер запускается. перезагрузил его и все запахало.
Вот ведь иногда как бывает =(
Спасибо дружище большое!